# Statistical significance of hierarchical (multi-level) associations

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multilevel-analysis, multiple-comparisons

[Association rule mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) is a common technique in Data mining used to find itemsets which appear together very frequently in large transaction databases (e.g. in Table 3 we see that in a transactions database milk and bread are bought very frequently).
For checking statistical significance of such patterns we can generate random data that would imply no association between the items of the pattern in the Null hypothesis. Then we can compute the p-value with some interest measure and check for significance.

Now, if we introduce a hierarchy in our data where the items forming the pattern might be at multiple-levels, e.g., if we want to check for statistical significance of the association between Dairyland and bread in the [image] attached from this [paper](https://www.vldb.org/conf/1995/P420.PDF), how do we check for statistical significance of such patterns?